# How to write program in Silverlight that would do something every 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to write program in Silverlight that would do something every 10 seconds, eg, process twitter search results? The closest I came up is this:

```
        // Get and process new twitter search results evey 10 seconds
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Get results of Twitter Search and process them in the above code
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + keywords + "&show-user=true", UriKind.Absolute));

                // wait 10 seconds beofre getting new twits
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

but it not work. plz help.

Comment: I think you mean tweets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the code to be excuted on the UI thread, you need `DispatcherTimer`. See this [post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Tip-Asynchronous-Silverlight-Execute-on-the-UI-thread.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `System.Threading.Timer`. All the official documentation with sample code at the bottom: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx